# Bloquear caja de texto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda respecto al bloqueo de una caja de texto, lo que pasa es que al cargar la página, la caja de texto esta bloqueada, pero cuando guardo información y recargo la página se puede editar la información de la caja que debería estar bloqueada. Como manejo horas de entradas de empleados es importante que no puedan modificar la hora.

Aquí esta mi código:

```html
    <input type="text" name="timePunchIn" class="timePunch timefield timeIn" id="timePunchIn" value="${iteration.startTime}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Agradezco su ayuda, saludos

Comment: Has intentado utilizar el atributo `disable` de HTML?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con: *guardo información*?

Comment: @alexchvrches sería `disabled` (con una d al final)

Comment: Independientemente de la comprobación/restricción que añadas en el lado del cliente con HTML/JavaScript, tienes que asegurarte en el lado del servidor de no procesar el dato.

Comment: Tal y como te comenta @AlvaroMontoro, no deberías limitarte solamente a las comprobaciones desde HTML/Javascript, ya que estos son fácilmente accesibles y se pueden manipular para saltarte estas restricciones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **DISABLED**

El atributo `disabled` es un atributo booleano.

Cuando está presente, especifica que el elemento  debe estar deshabilitado.

Un elemento de entrada deshabilitado no se puede utilizar y no se puede hacer clic.

El atributo desactivado se puede configurar para evitar que un usuario use el elemento  hasta que se cumpla alguna otra condición (como seleccionar una casilla de verificación, etc.). Entonces, un JavaScript podría eliminar el valor deshabilitado y hacer que el elemento  se pueda usar.

Consejo: los elementos deshabilitados  en un formulario no serán enviados.

```html
    <input type="text" name="timePunchIn" class="timePunch timefield timeIn" id="timePunchIn" value="${iteration.startTime}" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado disabled y funciona.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" disabled>
  </body>
</html>
```